# How to detect if user is interacting with "File Tab" in PowerPoint?

Tags: .net, vba, powerpoint, vsto

I am looking for a way to determine when a user clicks the "File Tab" (and potentially any of the sub tabs marke the following dialog is shown in PowerPoint (see screenshot).[image]

I tried checking the ActiveWindow.ViewType but it does not change when the user opens the dialog. I also tried checking the Panes for their respective "Active" Property but it also does not change when the user is on this screen.

I also tried this code, but to no avail.

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function

    If GetForegroundWindow() <> Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.HWND Then
         Exit Function
    End If
```

I noticed that Keyboard input is not possible while this dialog is shown but I don't know how to check this within a VSTO solution. User32 IsWindowEnabled() returns True when the dialog is shown.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backstage UI provides two callbacks you are interested in:

- onShow

```
VBA: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnShow(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnShow([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

- onHide

```
VBA: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnHide(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnHide([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

Read more about that in the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I have to place the callbacks in a VSTO solution with a Ribbon (made with Visual Designer)? Or is this only possible if I convert the ribbon to XML and add e.g.   <backstage onShow="Backstage_OnShow"> ?

Comment: Unfortunately not all Fluent UI features are available in the ribbon designer. You have to deal with Ribbon XML if you can't find it in the designer.